# Text align problem when using Arabic font

Tags: android, android-edittext, arabic, text-alignment

The screenshot below displays my problem.

The first `EditText` shows a hint in Arabic which is shifted upwards, now the second `EditText` is just for reference which shows the English version completely fine. Same goes for the `Button`.

I have declared the string in `strings.xml` like this:

```
<string name="ar_login">دخول</string>
```

[image: screenshot of the problem]

This is how I set the EditText's hint:

```
UserName.setTypeface(ArabicFont);
String hint = getString(R.string.ar_HintUserName);
....
UserName.setHint(hint);
```

**UPDATE:**
I used this, but of no use:

```
UserName.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

But with this, Text moved a little down; but i guess its not generic:

```
UserName.setPadding(0,15,0,0);
```

With `Padding`, `English` words move to downwards.

**UPDATE 2:**
Originally arabic texts are separated; means they are shown letter by letter. So to join them, i was using this [Arabic Reshaper](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/UnTagged/al-qalam/org/amr/arabic/ArabicUtilities.java.htm). To Download Code, Check this [link](http://blog.amr-gawish.com/110/arabic-reshaper-goes-open-source-codename-barbetter-arabic-reshaper/)

Now when i reshape the arabic text and then set on `TextView` or as `EditText's` Hint, it got shifted upwords but without reshaping it is fine.

So i guess, whether i have to change the reshape class OR make my textview to not split the word. But dont know where to go?

Comment: This looks like an android issue. Did you try playing with the `gravity` attribute?

Comment: I think this is language(Arabic, English) dependent problem. use padding_top to manage it.

Comment: With padding_Top, i have two issues: first it wont be generic, second i have to change padding back to original for English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am still unable to find out why Android splits the arabic words into separate letters anyhow in my second edit I am providing a link which uses a class to rejoin the separated letters and form a word again.

In the `reshape` function, it was mistakenly appending `\n` at the end, just removing it solves the problem.

Comment: you dont know the power of "backspace" ?? :P

Answer (score 1):

I am sure its problem with the font file which you are using.!

[Sorry I am not allowed to upload the screen shot as my reputations are lower :(]

For the layout, I was setting text in xml, and typeface in code. And I'm not setting any attributes like padding/gravity. But  it was working fine for me.

So, I can assure you that using font file whose style matches your requirement will solve your problem.

Just to help you out with, but 'm not sure I got font file from  [DroidSansFallback.ttf](http://www.mediafire.com/?v5ztet2d3yr)

Comment: With the attached file the results are same. Can you send me the file you were using, on my email address in my profile? i m really unable to solve. i tested with another font file but same result.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess :) ...,

1. What if the size of the Arabic font is lower? [If this is the case, then Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL should have worked for you :( ]
2. May be this is the  style of that font file. How about trying a different font file for Arabic text ?

Comment: I appreciate but its not working. 

  1. Font size isn't a issue, but still i checked with gravity thing; same result.

  2. Checked with a different font file; same result.. :(